# ¿Cómo activar GPS, estando bloqueado el teléfono?

Tags: android-studio, gps

Buscando en la red encontré un código que calcula las coordenadas de ubicación. Luego de adicionar un par de lineas de código, logre que al abrir la app y cambiar de ubicación el teléfono genere un sonido, funciona bien.

¿Hay alguna forma de que este mismo código, se active y suene el audio, cuando el sensor perciba que el teléfono se ha movido, estando bloqueada el telefono o sin estar abierta la app?

Leyendo en algunas entradas no se si entendí bien o mal, dice que se debe hacer con un servicio o con un listener que escuche el sensor cuando se mueva el teléfono, no entiendo muy bien como implementar esa parte.

Gracias

```
public  class GPStracker extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

MediaPlayer audio;

Context context;
public GPStracker(Context c) {
    context = c;

}


public Location getLocation() {

    audio = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.audio);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Permisson not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

    boolean isGPSEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER );

    if (isGPSEnabled) {
        lm.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,10,this);
        Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER );

        return l;

    }else{
        Toast.makeText( context,"Please enable GPS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }

    return null;
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    audio.start();

}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
```

}

Comment: No es preciso, android al usar listener te quita presicion y es probable que solo se detecte el cambio de ubicacion cuando el usuario vuelva a abrir la aplicacion

Comment: Gracias por contestar @Junior Usca , ¿de que forma podría hacer para que el audio suene cuando el sensor del teléfono perciba que se movió, estando bloqueado o no bloqueado el teléfono?

Comment: Hola, alguien me puede dar una pista o un ejemplo de como lograr lo que quiero con mi código. Lo que quiero es que al mover el teléfono se active la alarma (sonido), incluso cuando este bloqueado. Gracias